# How can I test a heroku database on travis securely?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, clojure, travis-ci, ring

I'm using Ring(Clojure) on Heroku and I'm implementing some tests in the app. Some of the tests are `GET` requests to the app, and the app has a PostgreSQL database that fills some pages. But, to do so, the app has to connect to the original Heroku database.

How can I test if some content is present in a `GET` request without putting the database connection specs (url, user, password) in the `.travis.yml` file? Am I even supposed to do that? Or should I just setup a test database, fill it with test data and test the contents, with a `localhost` connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could put the credential in a [Travis Encryption key](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/). The only problem is that Pull Requests cannot use the decrypted keys (for security purposes).